# Can I get Code for getting location of text in PDF

Tags: pdf, itext, location, coordinates

I am facing problem with getting exact Coordinate of text, So can I can get whole code for this problem(Including myLocationExtractionStratey class as well).

Comment: What have you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This is not how you ask questions here, so the short answer to your question is: no. What did you try until now? Did you try to [find](https://lmgtfy.app/?q=getting+location+of+text+in+PDF) out for yourself?